# Gulp-Sourcemaps, SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

Gulp / npm noobie here.

I'm trying to use gulp-sourcemaps, and for some reason, it crashes on `var sourcemaps = require('sourcemaps')`.(It crash only when this line's in the file)

gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


gulp.task('generateApp', function () {
    return gulp.src([some paths...])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path...));
});
```

Error :

```
C:\Projets\node_modules\strip-bom\index.js:2
module.exports = x => {
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projets\node_modules\gulp-sourcemaps\src\init.js:10:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Has anyone encounter this type of error?
I tried to google it, without any success.

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: Node : v6.8.1 gulp v3.9.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just started getting the same error and fixed it by replacing the code in `C:\Projects\node_modules\strip-bom\index.js`  with this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (x) {
    if (typeof x !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a string, got ' + typeof x);
    }

    // Catches EFBBBF (UTF-8 BOM) because the buffer-to-string
    // conversion translates it to FEFF (UTF-16 BOM)
    if (x.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
        return x.slice(1);
    }

    return x;
};
```

Then, I had to run `npm rebuild node-sass` to get it to work again. It seems to be an issue with an older version of the **Strip-bom** node module.

For more info, check this out: https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-bom/commit/e2a3c3b83706ee5baac284f3862d3f6b9e1564e5

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

This error is caused by using an older version of Node. The Strip-bom module is now using [ES2015 (ES6)](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies) syntax which requires Node 5.0+. (See Node's ES2015 support list [here](http://node.green/#arrow-functions))

To test your version of Node, run:

`node -v`

If it's less than 5.0, you'll need to update it. You can download the newest version of Node here:

https://nodejs.org/en/

After installing the new version of Node, I still needed to run `npm rebuild node-sass` to get Gulp up and running again.

The former answer will still work if you don't want to update your Node version, however, as [Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127974/louis) pointed out, manually editing node module files is not a best-practice.

Comment: This comment put me on the right path. I didn't wanted to hand-modify the file it self, so I installed an older version of gulp-sourcemaps (version 1.5.0) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Was receiving the same error & this post also put me on the right track, but was running node v0.wontTellYou ;) ~ so, decided to do a full upgrade to node v7 & the `npm rebuild node-sass` sorted the issue out too. There's probably some kind of dependency documented somewhere, but hey, it's fixed now.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Debian, but on my Windows machine it seems to be working completely fine even with a fresh npm install.  I wonder if anyone knows what might be happening?